# Branch cuts imaginary part

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts, branch-points

This is a very simple gap in my intuition about branch cuts. I have heard informally a statement of the type: if a complex function suddenly acquires an imaginary part at the point $x_0$ in the real axis, this point is a branch point.

Is this necessarily true? What is the scope of this affirmation and why is it true? Also, why are the functions that are multivalued (with respect to the polar coordinate on the complex plane), always multivalued only on its imaginary part? Why isn't there functions whose real part is also multivalued?

I'd appreciate a formal answer, but any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Also, why are functions multivalued with respect to the polar coordinate only, but only on its imaginary part?" I don't know what exactly you mean here. Could you clarify, perhaps with an example or two?

Comment: I think the statement and question by the OP are correct. For example, consider the function $f(x) = \sqrt {(x - C)}$. For $x > C$ the function is real and positive. For $x < C$ the result is imaginary, and multi-valued. A branch cut is made to ensure that a single imaginary value is selected as the appropriate, preferred solution.

Comment: @Arthur I have edited the question to hopefuly make it clearer.

Comment: @M.Wind, is not the function $f(z)=z^{1/2}$ multi-valued also for $z\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$?  $f(1) \in \{-1,1\}$, for example.

Comment: @mjw I mean the real part of the image.

Comment: @GaloisFan, sorry, not exactly following.  Please expound your comment a little.  What about the real part of the image?  Thank you.

Comment: @mjw I believe I'm being dense, but I don't know what might be confusing you to try and explain better. But my point is: why isn't the real part of the image of a function (wherever within the plane) multivalued?

Comment: The example, $f(z)=z^{1/2}$, is a special case of your function, with $C=0$.  The function is multi-valued everywhere (after recognizing a branch point at $z=0$ and choosing a branch cut).  For example, a branch cut could be the negative imaginary axis, (it shouldn't matter).  $f(1) \in \{-1,1\}$ and $f(i) \in \{ e^{i\pi/4}, e^{5i\pi /4} \}$, and $f(-1) \in \{-i, i \}$.  Notice that the branch cut cuts the domain, not the range.

Comment: Can we not have a holomorphic function whose real part is multivalued? For example, $f(z) = i \cdot \log(z)$?

Comment: @mjw it is not. The real part of the square root is not multivalued -- again, I'm not talking about where the branch point is or where the cut is placed.

Comment: @LiliFN omg! You are absolutely right, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is something garbled in the statement...

First, it is not clear to me what "suddenly" means. :)  The imaginary part of a holomorphic function may or may not "suddenly" become non-zero, depending on what one means by this.

But/and in any case, this is not a great criterion for "a branch point"... Possibly/presumably, $f(z)=\sqrt{z}$ is a prototype for the phenomenon dubiously described as above, in the sense that, yes, "suddenly", the square root becomes non-real as $z$ moves across $0$. But/and, yes, this does also presume that we have *some* definition/description of $\sqrt{z}$ that somehow extends "across" $0$... which is already an issue.

Altogether, I'm not a fan of whatever a corrected/clarified version of this "criterion" turns out to be, because (to my perception) it masks the genuine phenomena.

(A more genuine point is that "branch point" is an intrinsic thing, but "branch cut" is definitely not.)

EDIT: just to have an example: $f(z)={\root 3 \of z}$ can be construed as being real both on $z$ real and positive, and $z$ real and negative. But/and there is a branch point at $z=0$.

Comment: Well, for your example, are not $z =0$ and $z=\infty$ the branch points?  So, agreed, the branch points are intrinsic, but don't we need to define a branch cut, either a straight line, or just about any non-self-intersecting curve connecting these two points in the extended complex plane?  Perhaps branch cuts are needed to define certain other entities?  Can we ignore branch cuts and find a Laurent series in the region $0<|z|<\infty$?

Comment: @mjw, it depends what you mean by "need" to choose/define a "branch-cut". One bottom-line goal would be to create a region on which there _is_ a well-defined (holomorphic) square root, etc. There are traditional choices, but/and the real goal is to "kill off" non-trivial monodromy by "killing off" paths. But/and, in particular, there cannot be a Laurent series in $0<|z|<\infty$, in any case. The Monodromy Theorem and its consequences is the definitive explanation for this, I think.

Comment: I'm sorry about the confusion in my writing. The word 'suddenly' is unnecessary. And, of course, we may chose, without crossing singularities, where to put the cut emanating from a branch point and that if we assume that something at all happens beyond that point with the function it is because we already have a 'prescription' on it, which makes the question awkward.

Comment: @GaloisFan, I do think the genuine issue about "branch cuts" is to shrink the purported domain of a ("branch of") the function so that the Monodromy Representation becomes "trivial"...

Comment: @paulgarrett, yes, I meant that rhetorically.  There is no series in that region.  I was not familiar with the Monodromy theorem and just looked it up.  Very interesting, thank you for pointing that out along with motivation for defining branch cuts!

Comment: But suppose we are given a holomorphic function defined for $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ whose real part is zero for $x\leq x_0$ (staying on the real line for simplicity) and finite otherwise. Can we say $x_0$ is a branch point?

Comment: Ah.. well... maybe. I have to say that, to my mind, this is not an optimal way to think about "branch points", and all this stuff. We'd almost always have many more conceptual ways to know/see a "branch point". I am willing to believe that there is a true assertion here, but I do doubt that it is a thing that you'd want to put into your head and have it take up space.

Comment: @paulgarrett I see! Thank you.